# Cell array assignment performance in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance

I'm currently working on a project in matlab. In this project, I firstly wrote an **Agent** class， and then a collection of **Agent** classes called **AgentCollection**, which holds agents by an cell array. Finally, I wrote a **Model** class which generates the **Agent** instance and added it to the collection instance.

The program was really slow, so I use the profile tool to try to figure out what happened. Surprisingly, I found that the line of cell array assignment is very slow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNQh3.png)

The agentPool is a cell array in the **AgentCollection** class, and the pool is initially allocate with size (50000,1). I then tested the performance of cell array assignment outside of the object

```
tic

x = cell(100000,1);

for m = 1:1:100000
    x{m} = pbm;
end
toc
```

where pbm is an instance of model. This code actually runs fast. Why does the cell array assignment appear so slow? Can I use another data structure to improve the performance? Thank you very much!

Note that the **Agent**, **AgentCollection** and **Model** class are all subclasses of handle. My MATLAB version is R2016b.

Comment: Your statements : "*this code actually running really fast. My question is why the cell array assignment appears so slow?*"  Aren't these statements self-contradictory? How much time does a single instance of `pbm` take?

Comment: I’m sorry I may not make it clear. the code in my project works very slow, indicated by MATLAB profile viewer, the code line is
obj.agentPool{id} = agent;
the viewer shows the line was called 36850 times and consumed 357s.
However, the code I show up there is a simple script, in this script, the cell array assignment was called 100,000 times, and the tic,toc shows it only consums 0.03s, which is really fast.
pbm is an object instance in my workspace, just for test of the performance of cell array assignment

Comment: Apparently it doesn't have anything to do with the cell array and it is  your model taking that much time.

Comment: I'm guessing that the line `obj.agentPool{id} = agent` is both constructing an `Agent` object *and* assigning it to the cell array? If so, it's probably your constructor that is taking so much time, not the assignment, since you don't see that sort of problem when you assign using an existing object `pbm` in your other example.